# Programmatically Get VM Instance Network & Memory Info

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

This question is for Continuous Web Jobs.

**Main Questions**

How can we "VIEW" or programmatically "LOG" the current memory & network status of a VM running a Continuous Web Job?

**Background:**

Our web job is scraping some API and we keep getting 500 errors. We believe that the VM is firing too many threads for API requests - and then because of network limitations - when the responses come back, too many responses come back at the same time, overloading the VM's network limitations.

**Side Questions:**

How would you use MS Azure to Web scrape - and make sure you don't overload (in terms of memory + network) the VM it's running on?

(It seems that for background processing, these VMs are built for CPU calculation - not for Web/API scraping)

Comment: "*(It seems that for background processing, these VMs are built for CPU calculation - not for Web/API scraping)*" - this comment makes no sense. Azure VMs aren't built for any specific purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still using the Monitoring (Classic) APIs currently. I've not found a "non-classic" version of the API, but I've also not spent much time looking. Since a web job runs as part of the Web App you'll need to monitor the web app using the tools provided in the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Metrics Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.management.monitoring.metrics.aspx).

I found the API to be somewhat confusing, but spent sometime working with the PG to get it right. I've provided some sample code on the MSPFE github page at: https://github.com/mspfe/AzureMetricsAPISampleKit. Running the "tests" in this Solution will show you how to use the lib.

You first need to identify the web app by getting a list of them:

```
var webSpaceList = _webSiteClient.WebSpaces.List();
```

Then collect the availabile metrics:

```
foreach (var website in websiteList)
        {
            MetricDefinitionListResponse wsMetricListResponse = _metricsClient.MetricDefinitions.List(website.WebsiteResourceId, null, null);
            website.MetricDefinitionsList = wsMetricListResponse.MetricDefinitionCollection;
            website.MetricNamesList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var metric in website.MetricDefinitionsList.Value)
            {
                website.MetricNamesList.Add(metric.Name);
            }

            MetricValueListResponse wsValueResponse = _metricsClient.MetricValues.List(website.WebsiteResourceId, website.MetricNamesList, "",
                _timeGrain, _startDateTime, _endDateTime);
            website.MetricValueList = wsValueResponse.MetricValueSetCollection;
        }
```

From there you should have metric definitions and values. Sorry if this code is a little dated... but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Azure WebJobs run within your Azure App Service's web app (formerly called Websites). So, your capacity is governed by the size (and quantity) of Web App instances, whether free tier or one of the paid tiers. And you'd measure your utilization against the Web App instances.

Your side question, about how to use Azure to web scrape, is not answerable here: It's an opinion-based question with no right answer.